# Left outer join not showing second table as null

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Table structre
table 1

```
account 
123
1234
12345
123456

table 2
account
123
1234
12345
```

I want to return table a record `123456` on account for table1 and null for column 2 when it doesnt match table 2

```
SQL
SELECT  table1.account, table2.account
from table1 
left outer join table2
on (table1.account= table2.account)
```

Comment: You *did* explicitly request rows where `table2.dates = '19-jul-17'`

Comment: where clause is the issue, remove and check

Comment: what is your output after removing the where clause?

Comment: No repro with this specific query. Didn't expect to reproduce the issue in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` statement explicitly asked for *non-null* rows with `table2.dates = '19-jul-17'`

You should modify your query to check for nulls:

```
SELECT  
    table1.account, table2.account
from table1 
left outer join table2
     on (table1.account= table2.account)
where 
    t1.dates='20170719' 
    and ( table2.account is NULL 
          or 
          table2.dates = '20170719'
        )
```

This matches rows that have a specific date in the first table, and either null or a specific date on the second.

Note the date literal. The original query used a *locale-specific* format. This can fail easily faile in locales that don't use that format. Never mind the two digit year.

`YYYYMMDD` on the other hand is unambiguous.

**UPDATE**

Once the `where` clause is removed, NULLs are returned as expected :

```
declare @table1 table (id int)

declare @table2 table (id int)

insert into @table1 
values
(123   ),
(1234  ),
(12345 ),
(123456)

insert into @table2 
values
(123  ),
(1234 ),
(12345)

SELECT t1.id, t2.id
from @table1 t1
left outer join @table2 t2
on (t1.id= t2.id)
```

Returns

```
id     id
123    123
1234   1234
12345  12345
123456 NULL
```

If the question is "how do I get the non-matching row" the answer is use `WHERE tabl2.ID IS NULL`

Comment: A downvote *because*? A LEFT JOIN will *always* return NULL for mismatches. If a `WHERE` discards the mismatches, no NULLs will appear

Comment: sorry to confuse i have removed reference to dates.. please try again

Comment: @bbb without the dates, you *will* get nulls. That's no reason to downvote the *answer*. If you don't explain what you did and post the *actual* data and *actual* query

Answer (score 0):

Everything is OK in your query, If you are using any `where` clause, please remove and check, BTW i am not able to reproduce your issue. PFB attempt, The query gives expected result

```
create table #tmp1( ID int)
create table #tmp2( ID int)

Insert into #tmp1 values('123')
Insert into #tmp1 values ('1234')
Insert into #tmp1 values ('12345')
Insert into #tmp1 values ('123456')

Insert into #tmp2 values('123')
Insert into #tmp2 values ('1234')
Insert into #tmp2 values ('12345')

select * from #tmp1
select * from #tmp2

SELECT #tmp1.ID, #tmp2.ID from #tmp1 left outer join #tmp2 on (#tmp1.ID=#tmp2.ID)

drop table #tmp1
drop table #tmp2
```

The result is:

```
ID  ID
123 123
1234    1234
12345   12345
123456  NULL
```